# I'm getting this attribute error working with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.grid()

        labell = Label(self.frame, text="min: ")
        labell.grid()

        self.min = Scale(self.frame, from_=1, to=10, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                     command=self.updateMax)
        self.min.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
```

This is where the error supposedly is:

```
    def updateMax(self,value):
        self.max.config(from_=int(value)+1)
        self.max.config(to=int(value)+11)

    def compute(self):
        lower = self.min.get()
        upper = self.max.get()+1
        self.list.delete(0,END)
        for x in range(lower,upper):
            str = "{0:2d} {1:3d} {2:4d}".format(x,x*x,x*x*x)
            self.list.insert(END,str)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

ERROR!!

```
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'max'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please answer asap. Thanks.

Comment: The code you gave never defines a `self.max`.  All I see is a `self.min`.  Is this all of the code?

Comment: Where exactly have you defined `self.max`? I can't see it. (Thus, the error?!)

Comment: @iCodez and Ashish, this is all the code. I have to define max? I assumed that was what updateMax was doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is all of the code, then the problem is simple: you never defined `self.max` yet you try to use it here:

```
def updateMax(self,value):
    self.max.config(from_=int(value)+1)
    self.max.config(to=int(value)+11)
```

Perhaps you meant to use `self.min`, which you did define:

```
def updateMax(self,value):
    self.min.config(from_=int(value)+1)
    self.min.config(to=int(value)+11)
```

If not, then you need to define `self.max` *before* you use it.